# How to run dart http server over a remote server

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, dart

I have a server of Ubuntu 20.04, and I've successfully run a apache server and I can visit the site with ip address (or domain) from the Internet. But with dart it could be visited from the server with 127.0.0.1/localhost but I could not visit the site from the Internet. How could i fix the problem...?

- With dart

  - [Chrome Preview (Empty Response)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2YFd.png)
  - [zsh Preview (works well)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB9d8.png)

  ```sh
    dart run
  ```
- With Apache

  - [Chrome Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQHyx.png)

  ```sh
    systemctl start apache2
  ```

### What i have ever tried

1. close the apache server and change dart server port to 80, not working
2. add ports config in firewall

### Code

No dependency, all-code-in-a-file:

```sh
dart create tmp
cd tmp
vi bin/tmp.dart
dart run
```

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  print('Hello world!');
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 80).then((server) {
    server.listen((request) {
        request.response.statusCode = 200;
        request.response.write("---");
        request.response.close();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4` is `127.0.0.1` so your are only allowing traffic coming from the same server your application are running. Try use`InternetAddress.anyIPv4` instead.

Comment: @julemand101 Thanks!!! It works!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @julemand101, it's all my faults…… Simply change `InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4` to `InternetAddress.anyIPv4` works fine!